# AJAX POST returns 404 Spring

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring

I am trying to make a POST call using AJAX. Here's my controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/submitsignup")
    @ResponseBody
    public String persistSignupData(@RequestBody SignupModel signupModel) {
        signupDaoImpl.persistSignupData(signupModel);
        return "success";
    }
```

***Javascript:***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#password2").keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
    $('#signup-button').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/cinestop/submitsignup",
            data: JSON.stringify(getFormDataJSON()),
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json"
        });
    });
});
```

When I make the call, a 404 is returned. I have been unable to debug this problem till now. What is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Avoid stringifying the JSON, since your datatType expected is JSON.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#password2").keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
    $('#signup-button').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/cinestop/submitsignup",
            data: getFormDataJSON(),
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json"
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I just did that, and unfortunately, it does not solve the problem :(

Answer (score 1):

> When I make the call, a 404 is returned.

Did you ensure that you put the correct url in your ajax part..?
HTTP error 404 usually means that the document that you'r requesting can't be loaded because it's

1. not existing
2. it is not readable
3. the mime type for the document is not defined (usually a problem of common webservers, i dont think that this matches on your specific setup)

Quote of relevant code

```
url: "/cinestop/submitsignup",


@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/submitsignup")
```

Comment: i don't think so. if an error occours at processing the submittet data, the server should return a responsecode like 500. if your mapping is actual fine then you have to take a look to your routines to handle errors while processing the request. thats absolutely NOT normal that you get the statuscode 404 instead of 200 oder 5xx.

Answer (score 1):

First try to debug the application step by step

From `postman`, `curl` or any other rest client try to hit a `post` call with the payload body as empty `JSON`.If this also return 404, then it is a server problem.If it succeeds or throw any java error then we know it is UI error.Also make sure to add content type header as '`application/json'`

This will help in isolating the issue and will help us in giving a quick resolution

Comment: I used CURL and it returns a 404. What might be the problem on server-side?

Comment: I am assuming that your post url now is domain.com/appName/controllerName/submitsignup . Hence your controller is annotated with "cinestop" path

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this solution:

```
var settings = {
        "url": "/cinestop/submitsignup",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "data": getFormDataJSON()
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
     console.log(response);
});
```